# Writing a Hierarchy to file?

Tags: c++, file, hierarchical-data

Is there a common approach to writing a hierarchy of data to a file?  I'm having trouble visualizing how such a structure would exist in a 1 dimensional structure like that, without writing something as complex as an XML parser/emitter. The hierarchy in this case has a single root node, where each node can have an arbitrary number of children.

(In my case, it's a hierarchy of bones/transforms in an animation rig)

Comment: XML and Json are two data formats that can be organized in that way.

Comment: I wish I knew what approach you were thinking of that seems so "very complex".  As it is, I can't even make a suggestion would be simpler than what you're imagining.

Comment: @DrewDormann - I'll add that into the question, my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is there a common approach ..."*

No there isn't. There are many approaches, varying from XML data, over raw serialization (e.g. [google protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)), [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), to custom text or binary formats.